# Contradiction regarding the continuity of a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, distribution-theory

Consider $ T \in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ defined as follows,
$$\phi \to T(\phi) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(n)$$

Next, let $\psi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be a function with support in $[-1,1]$ such that $0 \le \psi(x) \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and such that $\psi(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [-0.5,0.5]$. Next, consider the sequence
$$\phi_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n}}\psi(\frac{x}{n})$$
Note that $\phi_n$ converges uniformly to zero as $n \to \infty$, however, $T(\phi_n) \to \infty$. Does this contradict the continuity of $T$?

My attempt:

Since the question states $T$ is a distribution, it must be continuous and so I'm led to believe that I must show why this isn't a contradiction.

My thoughts are that $\phi_n \notin \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, and so $T(\phi_n)$ not converging to zero isn't a contradiction. I believe that for each $n$, $\phi_n(x)$ is in $C^\infty$ and smooth, as $\phi^{(k)}_n(t) = \frac{1}{n^k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n}}\psi^{(k)}(\frac{x}{n})$ and $\psi$ is in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and the terms in front of it will simply be a constant.

However, we can also note that the support of $\phi_n$ is given by $[-n,n]$. Thus, as $n \to \infty$, the support of $\phi_n$ also goes to infinity and hence, in the limit $\phi_n$ does not have compact support and so is not in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.

I'm not too confident in my answer, but I've been reviewing this question for awhile and can't think of anything else. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform pointwise convergence is certainly *necessary* for convergence of $\varphi_n$ in test functions, but it is not sufficient. One further requirement of a Cauchy sequence (and also Cauchy net!) is that the supports be (uniformly) bounded. A sequence such as you constructed definitely does not have this property. So your $\varphi_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence in the space of test functions, so there's no paradox here.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to understand the reasoning - Am I correct in thinking that if $\phi_n$ is a Cauchy sequence  that converges to zero, then $T(\phi_n) \to \infty$ would mean $T$ is not continuous. And your point is that since the the support of the sequence is not bounded, it is not a Cauchy sequence and thus, this is not a contradiction. Let me know if I've messed anything up in my thinking here.

Comment: Yes, indeed, if $\varphi_n\to 0$ (in the topology of test functions), by the definition of (sequential) continuity, $T(\varphi_n)\to 0$. So if $T(\varphi_n)\to+\infty$, it could not have been that $\varphi_n\to 0$.

Comment: And the reason the sequence $\phi_n$ is not bounded is because the support is given by $[-n,n]$ for each $\phi_n$, which is unbounded as $n \to \infty$, correct?

Comment: Never-mind, I see what you're saying. For $\phi_n$ to converge to zero in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ we must have that there exist a compact interval $I$ such that $Supp(\phi_n) \subset I$ for all $n$, which clearly isn't the case since the support of $\phi_n$ is $[-n,n]$ which is unbounded. Thank you!